# Getting verbose feedback for systemctl commands

Tags: systemd, services, sysvinit

One of my biggest issues with `systemd` is the lack of any feedback when starting/stopping/restarting a service.

With `sysvinit`, I'd get the following after issuing `service openvpn restart`:

```
[ ok ] Stopping virtual private network daemon: <server_name>.
[ ok ] Starting virtual private network daemon: <server_name>.
```

This would also flag up any errors that could then be hunted down in the logs and debugged.

With `systemd` I get no feedback at all.

Of course I don't expect `systemd` to clone `sysvinit`'s functionality; I'm just asking if there's a similarly verbose output option possible.

Comment: Note that it does log to `/var/log/syslog`, not standard output, as one might expect. Though even this output does not clearly indicate a restart - for `polkitd`, for example, it just shows it starting up. There might be some way of getting it to output to standard output. Just stopping `polkitd` gives no output at all.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - no output at all here means success. With `systemd` they said (iirc) _"we assume success and only inform the user in case of failure"_ . Also, depending on implementation/admin the file `/var/log/syslog` may be missing (most non-debian+derivatives) so you're better off using `journalctl -b -u some.service` and/or `systemctl status some.service`.

Comment: @don_crissti Well, I agree with the poster that there should at least be a verbose mode that explicitly shows the starting and stopping of the daemon. There is an argument to be made that this should happen by default. Is there any kind of Unix standard that says what should happen here, I wonder.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - :) Well, I also agree with the poster, there should be a `-v` switch for those who need/want it though I don't think this should be default... `systemctl` is in line with many other commands (when you `mv` a file there's no `OK` if the operation was successful). There's no standard that I know of...